# Product of $\prod_{n=0}^{k-1} \frac{-1}{(4n+4)(4n+3)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, products

Is there any way of expressing $$\prod_{n=0}^{k-1} \frac{-1}{(4n+4)(4n+3)}$$ as some special function? I can get factor some things out and get $$\frac{(-1)^k}{4^kk!}\prod_{n=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{4n+3}$$ but this last thing is recalcitrant. It's something like a quadruple factorial, but I haven't seen much about those. This arises from the series solution to $y''+x^2y=0$.

Comment: Help by [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=prod%281%2F%28n-1%2F4%29%2Cn%3D1..k%29)

Comment: OP is not seeking an infinite product.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni. Hi Raymond ! Long time no speak. Cheers :-)

Comment: Happy new year @ClaudeLeibovici and a great continuation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a product of the terms of an arithmetic progression, then you can factor out the "step size" and then use the gamma function.
$$
\prod_{n=0}^{k-1}\left(an+b\right) = a^k\;\prod_{n=0}^{k-1}\left(n+\frac{b}{a}\right)
$$
The gamma function satisfies the recurrence relation
$$
\Gamma(z+1) = z\Gamma(z)
$$
which in turn means
$$
\Gamma(z+m+1) = z(z+1)(z+2)\cdots(z+m)\Gamma(z) = \Gamma(z)\prod_{n=0}^{m} (z+n)
$$
Now set $m=k-1$ and $z=\frac{b}{a}$ und you get
$$
\prod_{n=0}^{k-1}\left(an+b\right) = a^k\;\prod_{n=0}^{k-1}\left(n+\frac{b}{a}\right)
=a^k\;\frac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{b}{a}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}
$$
In your specific case, this means
$$
\prod_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{-1}{(4n+4)(4n+3)}
=\frac{(-1)^k\;}{4^k\;k!}
\;\cdot\;
\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{4^k\;\Gamma\left(k+\frac{3}{4}\right)}
=\frac{(-1)^k\;\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{4^{2k}\;k!\;\Gamma\left(k+\frac{3}{4}\right)}
$$